# monitor grandchild processes spawned by Python's Popen subprocess

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I can successfully process the STDOUT of a process I spawn with:

```python
print("launching child")
child=subprocess.Popen(params,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in child.stdout:
    #do processing
    print("processed:"+line.decode())
print("child dead :(")
```

However, the child process (not under my control) likes to sometimes "restart" itself, either for UAC reasons or otherwise. When it does this, the for loop exits and on windows the grandchild process's STDOUT goes straight to the console. For example:

```
(venv) > .\parent.py
launching child
Processed:woot I started
Processed:doing stuff
...
Processed:shutting down for restart
child dead :(
(venv) > woot I started
doing stuff
```

I'd like to still be able to process the grandchild's output. Any ideas on how to do this?